# Maven copy-dependencies: not all dependencies copied?

Tags: maven

This question is about Maven. My project has `spring-boot-starter-parent` as its parent. Mvn Repository's [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.5.RELEASE), shows that through all parent hierarchies, `spring-boot-starter-parent` has 273 dependencies in total.

However, when I run the goal [dependency:copy-dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html), I get only a handful of jars, and in particular, I notice that `javassist` is not one of the jars. Why aren't the jars for all 273 dependencies copied by `dependency:copy-dependencies`? Can Maven somehow tell if some of these dependencies are not needed by my project?

Comment: Do you have a plugin configuration in your project pom?

Comment: You should read the docs about Spring boot and use the spring-boot-maven-plugin which handles everything....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 273 managed dependencies in `spring-boot-starter-parent`. Managed dependencies are just there to give maven details about libraries your project uses when it needs it. They are not actually included in your project when it gets built. The dependencies included are those in your project's `<dependencies>` section and their transitive dependencies. Hence the difference you see.